# I want to make a multiple directories in one directory with a script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make multiple directories in linux.

My location is /myhome/docs/

within this I want to make 46 folders with tag as sample1,sample2,sample3... sample46

How do I make this?

Can anyone help me with a simple script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late - but for fun, a collection:

1.) The direct method, as others says:

```
mkdir sample{1..46}
```

It calls only one times the `mkdir` because the parameter expansion occurs before the `mkdir` is executed. It seems be a good idea, but fails on

```
mkdir sample{1..100000}
```

with error like:

```
-bash: /bin/mkdir: Argument list too long
```

Also, it is very hard to use in scripts, because you can't do the next:

```
count=46
mkdir {1..$count}
```

2.) using a for-loop

```
for((i=1;i<=46;i++))
do
    mkdir "sample$i"
done
```

will work for any number of directories, but it isn't efficient - will call mkdir (fork/exec) for every directory.

3.) Using `seq`

```
for i in $(seq 46)
do
    mkdir "sample$i"
done
```

works too, but again will call `mkdir` each times, and for the large numbers must allocate long argument list for the `for` loop.

4.) a variant of `seq`

```
seq -f "sample%g" 1000000 | xargs mkdir
```

will call the `mkdir` only minimum necessary times, and will not fail on any count of directories.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
mkdir sample{1..46}
```

OR using for loop for more control:

```
for ((i=1; i<=46; i++)); do mkdir "sample$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mkdir sample{1..46}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

This must be of use:

```
mkdir sample{1..46}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below code also,

```
for i in $(seq 46); do mkdir "sample$i"; done
```

Comment: Note `{1..46}` alone would make the same and it is preferred over the external `seq()` when the values are set before hand.